# Is it possible to make a user that is creator and runner in AAE11.1?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, rpa, automationanywhere

I'd like to scheduled a robot but on my own computer at 9AM but if I'm connect on AAE with my bot creator's account the task failed **'Automation failed due to deploy failure'**.

Can I make a bot runner and creator to solve this issue or maybe can I run a scheduled task on a bot creator ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible, Control Room scheduled tasks only work on unattended bot runners.
You can schedule the task locally on the client.

As Control Room Admin, make sure that every runner account is running on each machine.
As Developer, develop on different machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a schedule task on a bot creator, but that will limit you to a "One Time Only" schedule. This may or may not work for your specific case. You can use the Tools > Schedule Manager on the local client to setup a "One Time Only" scheduled task for a specific date/time.

[Their documentation states](https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v11.3/page/topics/aae-client/bot-creator/working-with-automation-tasks/scheduling-tasks-to-run.html) "client users with task creation privileges can only test run the tasks using the 'One Time Only' schedule option. However, Bot Runners - Client users with run time privileges, can continue to schedule tasks using various options if using Enterprise edition 10.2. and above." Trying to use a bot runner to schedule a bot creator task of running a one time only task would not help you.